# Docker Django uWSGI strange connection error

Tags: django, docker, uwsgi

I'm trying to test a production environment of a Django app in a docker container, using a uWSGI server. My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY config/requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "./uwsgi.ini"]
```

and my uwsgi.ini like this:

```
[uwsgi]
http = :8000
chdir = ./
module = testproject.wsgi
master = 1
processes = 2
threads = 2
```

When I build the container and run it, everything seems to work, but when I visit localhost:8000, rather than seeing my app, I get this error:

```
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:61104" (3 retries): Connection refused
```

I have no idea where this 61104 port is coming from (it's not specified anywhere), but I think the issue is that uWSGI can't properly connect to django...

I've tried setting debug=False in the settings.py, and also adding that weird port to allowed hosts, but no dice. 
If anyone knows the answer to this I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I am not familiar with uWSGI's config syntax _but_ have you tried "http = 0.0.0.0:8000" in uwsgi.ini to indicate what interface to bind to?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for this. I did try that - I think something in my config was messing with uWSGI. Either that or it wasn't playing nice with the conda virtualenv I was using. I've gone for gunicorn instead and things are working... thanks!